# How to select text View from website as a default text view in android Web View?

Tags: android, url, download, youtube, android-webview

I want to make an android app in which I want to open a website inside web view in my app and I want to paste YouTube URL inside the website and I want to download the URL video.

I just want to copy the URL and set this URL automatically inside the website. When the user clicks a button the link will automatically be pasted inside the website URL area.

How I can do it.

I have explained it in images.

Here is in this image I have marked the area where the link will be pasted.

When I click the button, the URL link I have copied should be automatically pasted inside the marked area, so I can download the video using this website from YouTube.
`textView.setText(Url)`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to either fill input field or add an onclick listener. The would be something like this:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and execute javascript like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('inputFieldID').value = 'my url that I want to copy';");
```

Do make sure that you do this when the page is loaded, otherwise you won't find that element!

This also means you could click that button after you've set the value, but its getting kinda creepy now

Comment: i want to open this website  http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/ in my app and and i want to paste my URL which i have copied from YouTube inside the area in website for downloading video. so how can i access this area from website which i have mentioned can access. can you please open the website for checking. to just under stand my question.i will be very thankful to you

Comment: Ok call `myWebView.loadUrl("http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/")` before you execute the javascript, and wait for the page to load. There is enough to be found on the internet about this topic

Comment: i want to open this website en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video in my app and and i want to paste my URL which i have copied from YouTube inside the area in website for downloading video. so how can i access this area from website which i have mentioned can access. can you please open the website for checking. to just under stand my question.i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: The id of that input field is `sf_url` meaning you will get `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sf_url').value = 'my url that I want to copy';");`

Comment: and where will i paste the website link in web view. the website that i will open in web view.
myWebView.loadUrl("http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-‌​youtube-video/")
just before these lines?
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sf_ur‌​l').value = 'my url that I want to copy';");

Comment: these lines of code are not working brother can you provide me a complete code?